# how do i remove nodes with their children but keep ones that are already connected?

Tags: graphs

suppose you have graph G and you want to remove node n and n and all of his children but keep the ones that are connected to other nodes

[image]

if i want to delete A it will delete C but not D becase its connected to B.
and if i want to delete D then E will not be deleted because it is connected to A

is there

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to look at the *in-degree* of a vertex.  For every *out-neighbors* of the vertex you want to delete, decrease the in-degree by one.  If the the in-degree drops to zero, you should delete the child.

It's not clear if you want to do this recursively as well, but that shouldn't be an issue.  (I.e., if you have the total ordering a→b, b→c, a→c, and you delete a, should to delete b and c as well?)